# How to export images along with module in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular

I have a new Angular project with only 1 component, a header. The header has a logo image in it. I'm setting it in the component's constructor:

```
export class AppHeader {
  logoImage: string;
  constructor() {
    this.logoImage = '/assets/images/logo.png';
  }
}
```

Then in the template I do `<img [src]="logoImage" />`.

Now I've created a module with this component in it, to be exported and consumed in a ***second*** angular project:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { AppHeader } from './app-header.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppHeaderComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    AppHeaderComponent
  ]
})
export class AppHeaderModule { }
```

This works great, except, it doesn't bring the images over. I've also tried just referencing the image directly in the template without adding it in the .ts file, i.e. just `<img src="assets/images/logo.png" />`.

Is there some step I'm missing or a different technique of exporting to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try <img [src]="'assets/images/logo.png'" /> ?

Comment: is the image moved to the dist folder on first project build? Btw even is the image is embedded in the build, you will find it in your node_modules in the second projet. So you will have to tell your build system for the second projet to get the images from the dependency.

Comment: Rafael - did not work. And thanks @PierreMallet, ya that seems like the right way to do it, copy the images from the node_modules package into my assets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Pierre's suggestion, instead of trying to export the images along with the component/module, I updated my angular-cli.json on the second project to copy the images over:

```
"assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico",
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "../node_modules/base-project/src/assets/images",
      "output": "./assets/images"
    }
  ],
```